# How to forbid the assignment to some attributes and update linked attributes of a Python object?

Tags: python

Just for instance,

```
c = myClass()
```

1. Attribute `x` of `myClass` is readonly. Trying to change `c.x` raises an error.
2. Attributes `a` and `b` of `myClass` are connected by `a=2*b`. When one changes, the other changes automatically too.

> 

```
c.a = 10 
# or setattr(c,'a',10) or c.__setattr('a',10)
# c.b becomes 5
c.b = 10
# c.a becomes 20
```

Comment: Do you have more code to show on how you attempting to achieve what you are trying to do?

Comment: Look into properties (the `@property` decorator).

Comment: You can use the magic method __setattr__

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`@property`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property).

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, x, a):
        self._x = x
        self.a = a

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self.a / 2

    @b.setter
    def b(self, b):
        self.a = b * 2
```

There is no setter for `x` so it is read only.