# sync one instance to another instance of different class in python

Tags: python, object, instance

I have two classes

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

class B():
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 2
        self.A = A()
        self.A.a = self.b
```

and one class contains the other as an instance (maybe inheritance would be better?).
I want some properties, say a, of that A instance to be synced some properties of the containing B instances, say b. So in this example

```
B_instance = B()
print(B_instance.A.a)
B_instance.b=3
print(B_instance.A.a)
```

the first print statement gives 2 and the second one I want to give 3. But it gives 2, despite python passing by reference name.

Comment: `B.b` could be a `property` with a setter that uses `A.a`.

Comment: thanks @mkrieger1. What do you mean by that. Maybe a line of code? Like self.b=self.A.a? No you cant meean that

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968945/how-to-forbid-the-assignment-to-some-attributes-and-update-linked-attributes-of

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

An example using [property](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property). Try this:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

class B():
    def __init__(self):
        self.A = A()
        self.b = 2

    def set_b(self, value):
        self._b = value
        self.A.a = self._b
    def get_b(self):
        return self._b
    b = property(get_b, set_b)

B_instance = B()
print(B_instance.A.a)
B_instance.b = 3
print(B_instance.A.a)
```

Output:

```
2
3
```